# swiping down a fragment and taking a view to bottom|right on any other fragment like Youtube player does? (draggable panel deprecated)

Tags: java, android

I need exactly same work like youtube does. the way it minimizes the whole fragment and just keeps the player view ON, on any other fragment or activity.please provide a better resolution. The `draggable` panel is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this on your own using ViewDragHelper. Check out this link to see a sample of ViewDragHelper http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2014/09/01/dragging-with-viewdraghelper/

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer helped you please vote it